# Pressure degasser of water

Tags: solubility, water-treatment, carbon-dioxide

Currently, I am working on a project where we are using pressure degassing. The idea is to make a test setup where we lower the pressure in a flask to 'degas' the solution. The solution is just distilled water, but we plan on doing other water samples later on. The background of this project is associated with carbon capture from seawater, so we want to lower the pressure to a point where a lot of the carbon dioxide concentration in the water is moved to the gas part of the flask.

Given that we start at room temperature, and we don't want to remove ALL the carbon from the solution (due to marine life), what minimal pressure (or pressure drop in comparison with ambient pressure) would be recommended for this experiment?

Relevant papers are also very much welcome,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note also there are high levels of bicarbonate is sea water and intensive degasing would lead to alkalisation. There should be used pH threshold at which degassing should stop.

Comment: Also consider that at constant room temperature, water will boil at ~3kPa pressure, or if allowed not warmed, the temperature drops as pressure is reduced. See https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/boiling-point-water-d_926.html Also consider the **time** for this to equilibriate. Perhaps this is best determined by experimentation with known samples.